# Using hashmaps with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of data that is coming from an API with information about banking transactions. I want to loop through the array and add all transactions within the same month to get a total for the month to display in a bar graph using d3. I tried using a hashmap (see below) to get the outcome that I wanted but I cannot get d3 to draw the values onto the graph. Does d3 only work using arrays? Or is there a better method to doing this?

MODEL DATA (An array that can have n numbers of transactions per user)

```
[{ 
     id: 25,
     amount: 45.21,
     accountNumber: '1200548129',
     location: 'Account transfer',
     type: 'transfer',
     dateOfTransaction: '2022-04-06'
}]
```

HASHMAP RESULT (can be n number of hashes based on month selected within the year and year date.)

```
{Apr: 3825.09, Mar: 186104.94}
```

ACTUAL D3 ATTEMPT (The axes are displaying correctly but the bars will not render)

```
    const Dates: {
      1: string;
      2: string;
      3: string;
      4: string;
      5: string;
      6: string;
      7: string;
      8: string;
      9: string;
      10: string;
      11: string;
      12: string;
    } = {
      1: "Jan",
      2: "Feb",
      3: "Mar",
      4: "Apr",
      5: "May",
      6: "Jun",
      7: "Jul",
      8: "Aug",
      9: "Sep",
      10: "Oct",
      11: "Nov",
      12: "Dec",
    };
    transactions
      .filter((t) => {
        return t.dateOfTransaction.substring(0, 4) === year;
      })
      .map((t) => {
        const i: number = +t.dateOfTransaction.substring(6, 7);
        const items: { date: string; amount: number } = {
          date: Dates[
            i as keyof {
              1: string;
              2: string;
              3: string;
              4: string;
              5: string;
              6: string;
              7: string;
              8: string;
              9: string;
              10: string;
              11: string;
              12: string;
            }
          ],
          amount: t.amount,
        };
        if (DateAmount[items.date]) {
          const newAmount: number = DateAmount[items.date] + items.amount;
          DateAmount[items.date] = parseFloat(newAmount.toFixed(2));
        } else {
          DateAmount[items.date] = parseFloat(items.amount.toFixed(2));
        }
        return true;
      });

    const svg = select(svgRef.current)
      .style("background-color", "white")
      .style("overflow", "visible")
      .attr("width", CHART_WIDTH)
      .attr("height", CHART_HEIGHT);
    const x = scaleBand()
      .domain(Object.keys(DateAmount))
      .rangeRound([0, CHART_WIDTH])
      .padding(0.6);
    const y = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, max(Object.values(DateAmount))] as Iterable<NumberValue>)
      .range([CHART_HEIGHT, 0]);
    svg
      .append("g")
      .style("color", "black")
      .style("transform", "translate(0,100%)")
      .style("overflow", "visibile")
      .call(axisBottom(x));
    svg
      .append("g")
      .style("color", "black")
      .style("transform", "translate(100%,0)")
      .style("overflow", "visibile")
      .call(axisLeft(y));
    svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(Object.create(DateAmount))
      .join("rect")
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", (data) => CHART_HEIGHT - y(data as NumberValue))
      .attr("x", (data) => x(data as string) as string | number)
      .attr("y", (data) => y(data as NumberValue));
```

Comment: It's easiest to use d3 with arrays. Think it's doable by making the data look like: `[{month: 'Apr', total: 3825.09}, {month: 'May', total: 186104.94}]`

Comment: @Shreshth That is what I was assuming, I just did not know because I am new to using d3. Thank you for the guidance. It is truly appreciated.